# Limits and infinity minus infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

I understand that we need to rationalize when we have infinity minus infinity like here

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt{x^2 + 2}\right)$

My question is why can I not just split the limits like this

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right) - \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2 + 2}\right)$

and then

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2} * \lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{1 + \frac 1x}  - \lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2} * \lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{1 + \frac 2x}$

which gives

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2} - \lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2} = 0$

because $\frac 1x$ and $\frac 2x$ tend to $0$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: In order to say $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+2}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+2}$ it must be that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+2}$ exist as finite values separately.

Comment: The last line is wrong. Both limits are infinity. Formally this isn't defined. In general you can only split a limit of both parts exist, i.e are finite. Maybe the best way to convince you of that fact is to find a counterexample.

Comment: For counterexample... $\lim(n^2 - n) = \lim n^2 - \lim n = \infty - \infty = 0$  WRONG.

Comment: While it is true that $\lim \sqrt{x^2 + 1} = \lim \sqrt{x^2} \lim \sqrt{1 + 1/x} = \lim \sqrt{x^2}$, this doesn't help much because all three are equal to $\infty$. And you still can't conclude that $\lim \sqrt{x^2} - \lim \sqrt{x^2} = 0$ even though in both terms you're taking the same limit. What is true is that $\lim (\sqrt{x^2} - \sqrt{x^2}) = 0$, but you don't have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinity is not a number.

So there there is no general meaning to any "infinity arithmetic" expression.

*Sometimes*, though, there is a limit theorem which can be interpreted as an infinity arithmetic expression.

Here's one example of such a theorem:

> **Theorem:** Given sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb R$, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$, and if $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n + y_n) = \infty$.

Because of this theorem, one might argue that it is fair to "split the limits", as you say, resulting in the "infinity arithmetic" expression. 
$$\infty + \infty = \infty
$$
Fine so far.

But just because one can write an "infinity arithmetic" expression does not mean there is a theorem supporting that expression.

So, for example, there is NO theorem like this:

> **False Theorem:** Given sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb R$, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n - y_n) = $ BLAH.

It doesn't matter what you substitute for BLAH, the resulting statement will be false. Whether you substitute BLAH $=0$, or BLAH $= 1$, or BLAH $=42$ or BLAH $=$anything else, the resulting statement will be false.

To prove this, let me give you two counterexamples:

- Counterexample 1:  If $x_n = n$ and $y_n = n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \infty$, and 
  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n - y_n)= \lim_{n \to \infty} (n - n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0
  $$
- Counterexample 2: If $x_n = n$ and $y_n = n-1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$ and 
  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n-y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n - (n-1)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1
  $$

So, if you tried to convince me that the "False Theorem" was true using the substitution BLAH $=0$, I would show you Counterexample 2. And if you tried to convince me that the "False Theorem" was true using any substitution not equal to $0$, such as BLAH $=1$ or BLAH $=42$ or BLAH $=\infty$ or BLAH $=$anything else not equal to zero, then I would show you Counterexample 1.

In Calculus 1 we teach that the expression "$\infty-\infty$" is an indeterminate form. What this really means is what I've said above: there is no limit theorem which justifies any evaluation of $\infty-\infty$. When you encounter what looks like an $\infty-\infty$ expression, your best mathematical strategy is to **DO SOMETHING ELSE**, i.e. to re-evaluate the expression, rewrite it, alter it in some fashion (obeying the laws of algebra), so that it no longer has the $\infty-\infty$ form.

So for the opening example in your post, the mathematical strategy, as you say, is to rationalize the radicals. And you have probably learned other $\infty-\infty$ examples with different mathematical strategies.

Comment: How can we explain canceling the terms such as $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(n-n)$ 

Is it not $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate case? Can you look at my question here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810696/how-can-we-multiplydivide-the-expression-by-its-conjugate-in-the-infty-infty

Answer (score 6):

You can not subtract
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+2})=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+2},
$$
because the left hand side is $\infty-\infty$ which is not definable.

Instead, you can obtain that
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+2}=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+2})(\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+2})}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+2}}\\ =\frac{(x^2+1)-(x^2+2)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+2}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+2}}\to 0,
$$
where the properties of limits apply.

Comment: So i should split limits like this only when the result is a defined value ?

Comment: In general, you should try to transform the expression to something where the limits and their properties apply.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the fundamental flaw in the OP is in the assumption that $\infty-\infty$ has a meaning. This perhaps becomes more clear if we note that $\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+{1\over x}}=\sqrt{x^2+x}$, not $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, so the incorrect computation in the OP is actually for $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2+2x})$, for which a correct approach gives

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2+2x})=\lim_{x\to\infty}{-x\over\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2+2x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{-1\over\sqrt{1+{1\over x}}+\sqrt{1+{2\over x}}}=-{1\over2}$$

and not $0$.