# How can we multiply&divide the expression by its conjugate in the $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate case? Is it not $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

**Question**

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+5 x}\right)$$

To evaluate the limit, we multiply and divide the expression by its conjugate.

**First Question**

But since $x \rightarrow \infty$, we multiply it by $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ ? **Could you explain the reason clearly and in detail?**

\begin{aligned}
& \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+5 x}\right)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+5 x}\right)}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5 x}} \\
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2-\left(x^2+5 x\right)}{x+|x| \sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x}}} \\
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-5 x}{x\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x}}\right)}=\frac{-5}{1+\sqrt{1}} \\
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-5}{1+1}=-\frac{5}{2} \text { dir. }
\end{aligned}

**Second Question**

In the second step of the solution, how can we cancel the terms such as $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}(x^2- x^2)...$

Is it not $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate case?

Comment: You are using the conjugate before taking the limit. In each specific case where the conjugate is used, $x$ is finite.

Comment: when we multiply and divide a function  by same thing except for zero, we dont change the function, but we get rid of the undetermine form

Comment: In the second step of the solution, how can we cancel the terms such as $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}(x^2- x^2)...$ 

Is it not $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate case?

Comment: If you try to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x^2-x^2)$ by writing it as $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2 - \lim_{x\to\infty} x^2$, that doesn't work because you've created an $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate form. But the function $x^2-x^2$ is always equal to the function $0$ (that's just algebra, nothing to do with calculus); therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x^2-x^2)$ is equal to $\lim_{x\to\infty} 0$. This is the same lesson as for your original question: we are always allowed to do valid algebraic things to functions, even if there is a limit nearby.

Comment: X^2 - x^2 is not a limit. It is a very simple arithmetic expression that always has the result 0.

Comment: What's the "dir." at then end of the computation?

Answer (score 0):

for $x > 0,$   $$ x^2 + 5x <  \left(  x + \frac{5}{2}      \right)^2   $$
for$x > \frac{5}{8},$

$$ \left(  x + \frac{5}{2} -    \frac{25}{8x}   \right)^2 < x^2 + 5x <  \left(  x + \frac{5}{2}      \right)^2   $$
so  then
$$   x + \frac{5}{2} -    \frac{25}{8x} \; \;   <  \; \; \sqrt{x^2 + 5x} \; \; <  \; \;  x + \frac{5}{2}         $$